# Is the C++ * operator "already overloaded?"

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

My C++ teacher thinks that the * operator in standard C++ is "already overloaded," because it can mean indirection or multiplication depending on the context. He got this from *C++ Primer Plus*, which states:

> Actually, many C++ (and C) operators already are overloaded. For example, the * operator, when applied to an address, yields the value stored at that address. But applying * to two numbers yields the product of the values. C++ uses the number and type of operands to decide which action to take. *(pg 502, 5th ed)*

At least one other textbook says much the same. So far as I can tell, this is not true; unary * is a different operator from binary *, and the mechanism by which the compiler disambiguates them has nothing to do with operator overloading.

Who is right?

Comment: You are right. In a sense, it is fair to say that builtin operators already act polymorhpically depending on their arguments. That is static polymorphism

Comment: Note that in addition to there being two `*` operators (which is "overloading" in the English sense but not in the C++ sense), builtin binary `*` actually is also overloaded in the C++ sense, in that it applies to different types -- `int`, `double` etc. -- with different effects. The set of effective overloads for the purposes of operator overload resolution is defined in the standard, at 13.6/12. Likewise unary `*` is effectively overloaded for every pointer type (13.6/6) and function pointer type (/7).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both are right as the question depends on context and the meaning of the word overloading.

"Overloading" can take a common meaning of "same symbol, different meaning" and allow all uses of "*" including indirection and multiplication, and any user-defined behavior.

"Overloading" can be used to apply to C++'s official operator overloading functionality, in which case indirection and multiplication are indeed different.

**ADDENDUM**: See Steve's comment below, on "operator overoading" versues "*token* overloading".

Comment: So even the term "overloading" is overloaded.

Comment: To be precise, I think with the former meaning it's the `*` token which is overloaded, not the `*` operator. It's a very fine hair to split, though, I say it's the token just because the grammar of an expression using unary `*` is different from the grammar of an expression using binary `*`. You can imagine that they're both turned into `operator*(...)`, with one argument for unary and two for binary, in which case it behaves like a single overloaded function named `operator*`. That just isn't quite how the standard happens to define arithmetic expressions.

Comment: @Steve I totally agree and like that precision.  I would take that answer over mine. :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are. The dereference op and the mult. op are different operators, even if written the same. same goes for +,-,++,--, and any other I may have forgotten.

I believe the book, in this paragraph, refers to the word "overloaded" as "used in more than 1 way", but not by the user. So you could also consider the book as being correct... also depends if you're referring to the overloading of the * operator or of the multiplication operator (for example).

Answer (score 1):

It's overloaded in the sense that the same character is used to mean different things in different places (e.g. pointer dereference, multiplication between `int`s, multiplication with other built-in types, etc.).

Generally, though, "operator overloading" refers to defining an operator (that has the same symbol as a built-in one) using *custom code* so that it does something interesting with a *user defined type*.

So... you're both right :-)